# B-Tree Search referencing children data type issue

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, b-tree

So im trying to implement a Order 2 B-Tree however i am quite new to programming, especially in c++ I've created this struct for each node

```
    struct BTreeNode
{
    int data[2];
    BTreeNode **ChildLow;
    BTreeNode **ChildMid;
    BTreeNode **ChildHigh;

};
```

So when i try and set the next node to search as the child I keep getting compilation errors that it wants it of type BTreeNode, which it is isn't it?

```
bool search(BTreeNode *root, int value)
{
        BTreeNode currentNode = *root;
        bool found = false;
        bool searchComplete = false;
        while(found == false || searchComplete == false)
        {
            if (currentNode == NULL)
            {
                searchComplete == true;
                return false;
            }
            if (currentNode.data[1] == value)
            {
                found == true;
            }
            else if(value > currentNode.data[1])
            {
                if (currentNode.data[2] == value)
                {
                    found == true;
                }
                else if(value > currentNode.data[2])
                {
                    currentNode == currentNode.ChildHigh;

                }
                else
                {
                    currentNode == currentNode.ChildMid;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentNode == currentNode.ChildLow;
            }
        }


}
```

It also shows an error when i compare it to null.

Here are the errors:

```
1   IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands
        operand types are: BTreeNode == int
2   IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands
        operand types are: BTreeNode == BTreeNode **    
3   IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands
        operand types are: BTreeNode == BTreeNode **    
4   IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands
        operand types are: BTreeNode == BTreeNode **
```

1 being the Null error, the rest being the pointers to children

Any help would be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Compilation errors are neither shaken nor thrown, they are printed, and if you want any help you need to print them right here, in your question.

Comment: @user3105172 I've posted an updated answer, it should get rid of your errors, although i think you should have the struct with BTreeNode *childHigh instead of BTreeNode **childHigh.

Comment: What is the purpose of the extra level of indirection in your declarations: `BTreeNode **ChildLow;`?  Also those three names really get in the way of simple coding.  You would be much better off with `BTreeNode *Children[3];`

Comment: Why do you want a search function that returns just `true` or `false`?  There are many situations in which you need to know where it is when found and where it would have been if not found.  So you should think of a way for search to return that kind of information.

Comment: @JSF As long as it's just 3, i think having high, med and low allows for easier code reading as you don't have to remember who's who. I'm not sure, but i think that with regular trees you don't always write BTreeNode *Children[2] but you do BTreeNode *left, BTreeNode *right. Also, if he wants true or false it's his choice, we don't know what he'll be using the search for later...

Comment: @PiotrPytlik One of the main ideas of btree is to have *more than two* children in nodes, so having `left` and `right` is not a good option – it would reduce a btree to an ordinary binary tree.

Comment: In an ordinary tree, I always prefer `children[2]` rather than `left` and `right`.  Before you add re-balancing code, the simplifications possible using `children[2]` may be minor and not seem worth it.  But if you have any re-balancing, then the `left`, `right` naming forces you to write either two or four times as much re-balancing code compared to generically working with side `s` and side `1-s`.

Comment: @JSF Ok, I understand your comments now, I take back what i said about BTreeNode *Children[2].

Answer (score 0):

The first error you get is because currentNode is a BTreeNode instead of a pointer, which should be compared to NULL. A possible fix would be to instead do:

```
BTreeNode* currentNode = root;
/*...code...*/
if (currentNode == NULL)
/*...code...*/
if (currentNode->data[1] == value)
/*...code...*/
currentNode = currentNode->ChildHigh
/*...code...*/
currentNode = currentNode->ChildMid
/*...code...*/
currentNode = currentNode->ChildLow
```

Also note that when you type:

```
//searchComplete == true; this compares
searchComplete = true; // this assigns
```

and

```
//found == true; this compares
found = true; this assigns
```

you're not assigning true to searchComplete or found, you're actually doing a comparison.

**EDIT**

Also, if your node is just supposed to have a pointer to high, med and low children, you shouldn't be using '**', you should write

```
BTreeNode* childHigh;
BTreeNode* childMid;
BTreeNode* childLow;
```

which means that they point to your children.

Comment: Thanks, this was an issue, but not the one i mean, i am trying to set currentNode to the next node along, which is done by pointing it to the next child? i might be going about it all wrong but thats my intention anyway

Comment: Your first error is because you're comparing currentNode to NULL, where currentNode is a BTreeNode, not a pointer. I'll post a possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR.

Try this, then find out differences.

```
struct BTreeNode
{
    int data[2];
    BTreeNode *ChildLow;
    BTreeNode *ChildMid;
    BTreeNode *ChildHigh;

};

bool search(BTreeNode *node, int value)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->data[0] == value || node->data[1] == value) {
            return true;      // found!
        }

        // search in a subtree
        if(value > node->data[1]) {
            node = node->ChildHigh;
        } else if(value > node->data[0]) {
            node = node->ChildMid;
        } else {
            node = node->ChildLow;
        }
    }

    return false;  // at the bottom of the tree - not found
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything as to **WHY** it doesn't work properly, you're just saying "This is good code. Use this code."

Comment: @PiotrPytlik 1. Fixed assignments, thank you. 2. Too many errors to explain. Yes, I started writing quite detailed explanations – and abandoned when they became longer than the code. The OP didn't invent BTree but rather tries to implement an idea presented in some manual, book, paper, whatever. So here is an implementation to compare with the source and with their original code. Each difference indicates some detail of algorithm or language, which OP needs to learn about. Possibly this is not that straightforward, but IMHO much more fruitful way of learning.

Comment: I noticed the amount of errors while explaining. I'm not nitpicking, but if he wanted a proper implementation to understand, I'm sure this isn't the first one, seeing as there are usually examples in "manuals, books, papers, whatever". It's a good way to compare what he did wrong, of course, but he asked what was wrong, not how to properly implement this problem. You showed a good implementation, I explained (some of) his mistakes.